# Android framework

Tags: android

If someone asks me the below questions 
What an Android Framework is?
What does it do?

How should I answer?

Also what is the role of API's such as Activity Manager, Location Manager etc in the Framework?

Comment: What's the context? This sounds like a job interview or homework.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android framework. What is it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2968016/android-framework-what-is-it)

Answer (score 4):

`What an Android Framework is? What does it do?`

Application framework enabling reuse and replacement of components

`What is the role of API's such as ActivityManager?`

ActivityManager for interacting with the global activity state of the system.

`What is the role of API's such as LocationManager?`

LocationManager class provides access to the system location services.

** Keep the answers simple, as if you go in details you will face much harder questions, as you give the opportunity to be asked more into the core.

Answer (score 1):

> What an Android Framework is?

A: It is usually called as 'Android system server'.
There are many **encapsulated libraries**, such as 'xxxManager.class'.

> What does it do?

A: Actually does something **core functions**.

> What is the role of API's such as ActivityManager?

A: It is just **wrapped manager** to use Activity easily.

> What is the role of API's such as LocationManager?

A: It also **wrapped manager** to use something related GPS.

> More information briefly

A: If you cutomize Anroid framwork, you should understand about **AIDL(Android Interface Definition Language)**. 
AIDL is a middle transport between Android Application and Android System Server.

Comment: sry, not transport, it is a transporter